# HTML View in Android FlowTextView

Tags: android

i have used FlowTextView library from https://github.com/.
but my problem is when i display content from HTML it not display properly.

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>Unordered List with Default Bullets</h2>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>  

</body>
</html>
```

the above tags are my input, from that i must have below out put

Unordered List with Default Bullets

- Coffee
- Tea
- Milk

but i got.

Unordered List with Default Bullets
CoffeeTeaMilk

this is my android code

Spanned html = Html.fromHtml(content);
        flowTextView.setText(html);

please help me to escape from this stage.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using **TagHandler**

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<html><body><ul><li>....</li></ul></body></html>", null, new MyTagHandler()));
```

Use below **MyTagHandler** class for reference.....you can customize it as per your need.

```
public class MyTagHandler implements TagHandler{

boolean first= true;
String parent=null;
int index=1;

@Override
public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output,
        XMLReader xmlReader) {

    if(tag.equals("ul")) parent="ul";
    else if(tag.equals("ol")) parent="ol";
    if(tag.equals("li")){
        if(parent.equals("ul")){
            if(first){
                output.append("\n\t•");
                first= false;
            }else{
                first = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(first){
                output.append("\n\t"+index+". ");
                first= false;
                index++;
            }else{
                first = true;
            }
        }   
    }
}
}
```

Comment: sorry..! i am not sure where i implement class MyTagHandler. i am using FlowTextVIew class that extend  Relative layout, and corresponding functions if my knowledge is correct i must implement within FlowTextView Class!!!

Comment: no need to use FlowTextVIew library.... You can write MyTagHandler() class below onCreate()

Comment: okay but if i avoid FlowTextVIew i will face alignment issue.. because my data's(HTML) contains audio,video and images. i think i will struggle for proper alignment.

Comment: I think FlowTextVIew does not support <ul>,<li> tags... so above solution is for specific to those tag and you can get bullets from that class. You can further customize MyTagHandler() class as per your requirement.

Comment: hi... I tried but output.append("\n\t•"); is not working in FLowTextView.

Comment: As I have mention above, MyTagHandler() class has no relation with FLowTextView. You should try it with default Textview not FLowTextView.

Answer (score 0):

FlowTextView library has disadvantages. There is no need to do Html.fromHtml - the library does this for you. The view itself is the RelativeLayout and they use onDraw method to put your text there. That is why the text looks not good and the links are not clickable and other problems.

I would recommend to move to standard TextView and use Spans to create everything you want. Your links would be clickable, there are special spans for bullets, for text style and so on. This is native android mechanism for text styling. This maybe useful http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2014/01/31/spans/

Comment: Thanks for you valuable comment... i have html content along with audio,video, images so i am not sure TextView will support me to solve my requirement. Thats why i am moving to FlowTextView Library ....

Comment: I'm using LeadingMarginSpan2 for this purpose, it allows to create margin for defined number of lines in the paragraph